# Computed property needs to wait for async data

Tags: vue.js

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      projects: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get('...')
         .then(({ data } => this.projects = data)
  },
  computed: {
    personalProjects() {
          return this.projects.filter(...)
      },

      commercialProjects() {
          return this.projects.filter(...)
      }
  }
}
```

The computed properties need to wait for projects to be fetched from the server before setting the data. What's the proper way to do this?

I tried this:

```
watch: {
      projects() {
          this.personalProjects = this.projects.filter(project => project.type === 'personal')
          this.commercialProjects = this.projects.filter(project => project.type === 'commercial')
      }
  },
```

but I got an error message: `Computed property "personalProjects" was assigned to but it has no setter.`

Should I set `personalProjects` and `commercialProjects` in `data()` instead?

Comment: You'd either use computed properties or a watch with data properties but not both and they'd both be fairly equivalent in the end result.  What's the actual issue with your computed properties?  Can't you just wait until the ajax request is done before relying on their values?

Comment: What you have now seems correct.  Consider, how many of your currently loaded projects are "personal".  At initial load, there are no projects, so the empty array is correct.  Both computed properties will update reactively whenever `projects` changes after the request.

Comment: @zero298 thanks. your reply got me realize that I set 'projects' to an empty string initially. I changed to an empty array. Now it's working fine!

Comment: Ah, then nevermind my answer.  You were already taking the correct approach.

Answer (score 3):

What you are currently doing is the correct approach.  Computed properties are reactive, derived, properties.  They will reactively update whenever `projects` is updated by the data request.

In essence, your component's logic starts off with no projects, `[]` and if anyone asks for personal or commercial projects they are given the correct result: there are none of either, `[]`.

However, whenever the component is mounted, it starts the process of loading the actual projects and whenever it's done, the whole dependency graph of `projects` will be reactively updated meaning `personalProjects` will be provide the correct result.